# What is "X-Admin-Protocol" in HTTP Header?

Tags: http, header, admin, protocols

I read [ETSI Technical Specification 102 267.](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102200_102299/102267/11.00.00_60/ts_102267v110000p.pdf)
[image]

what's X-Admin-Protocol in HTTP header? When is it used?